# Размещение C# на сервере

Tags: c#, бот

Создаю бота для вк, который меняет название группы при помощи C# ASP.NET MVC. Но он работает только при обновлении страницы, а мне нужно чтобы он работал без контакта пользователей, и как мне сделать, чтобы название менялось каждый раз по принципу: "Если название группы не равняется этому, то сменить на это". Подскажите как реализовать. И да, еще один вопрос, можно ли обойтись без C# ASP.NET MVC?

Код:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(Bot);
        Timer timer = new Timer(tm, 0, 0, 2000);
    }

    public static void Bot(object obj)
    {
        string url = "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getChat?access_token=TOKEN&chat_id=1";

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        var response = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(response));
        JObject j = JObject.Parse(json);

        string title = (string)j["response"]["title"];
        int users = j["response"]["users"].Count();

        string name = "Тест, нас " + users;

        if (title != name)
        {
            url = "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.editChat?access_token=TOKEN&chat_id=1&title=" + name;
            webClient = new WebClient();
            response = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: c# приложение работает на сервере точно так же постоянно, как и на локальном компьютере. Можно сделать сервис и соединить их с ASP.NET, а можно использовать  self-hosted решения, например NancyFX, где "все в одном"

Answer (score 1):

Смысл технологии ASP.NET, это создание веб-приложений, отображаемых пользователям. Для запуска каких-то действий "без контакта пользователей", нужно делать службу или консольное приложение, запускаемое по расписанию.

Comment: А можете подсказать как это реализовать на сервере? Просто я новичок в этом деле, а наставника у меня нет =(

Comment: Посмотрите https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf, есть всё что нужно для разработки служб, документация с примерами имеется

Comment: Реализация служб и приложений на сервере ничем не отличается от реализации на настольном компьютере. Информацию по разработке служб можно найти, например, [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y817hyb6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: А если сервер на linux, то как поступать?

Comment: Не знаю. В Linux, естественно, нельзя воспользоваться концепцией службы. Но, в остальном, я полагаю, все так же. Консольные приложения должны работать везде одинаково.

Comment: Добавил код, может поможет чем.

Comment: Мне - ничем. Но уже вижу ошибку - переменная таймера должна быть полем класса, а не локальной переменной. Иначе сборка мусора ее раньше времени прибьет.

Comment: Переделал на WCF, залил на сервер. А как же мне теперь вызвать службу?

Comment: [Как-то так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb386386.aspx) Создать клиентское приложение, добавить ссылку на службу, вызвать метод. Но если WCF размещается в IIS, это не решит первоначальную проблему, так как IIS обрабатывает WCF-службы совершенно аналогично ASP.NET приложениям.

Comment: А как тогда быть? Я с это проблемой борюсь уже  битую неделю.